# Android gridview/imageholder dynamic layout

Tags: java, android, android-gridview

I'm having image holder with fixed height and width.
Based on user upload images, I want to make image space dynamically change like facebook images on the post.

1.For one image - allocate full space
2.For two images - divide half
3 For three images. top half two image and bottom one image.

How I can I make this division. ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Google's New Flex Box Layout

[FlexBox Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)